# Can I use Classify's model without internet or without FrontEnd?

Tags: machine-learning, deployment

Question1: without Internet
When I'm using a model trained by Classify in an Machine/Linux without internet,
I got the information:
`Loading from Wolfram Research server ...`

Can I skip this step by copying some related data/config into somewhere?

```
model=Import["model.wdx"]
model[data]
```

Question2:

Without FrontEnd, when you need download some resources such like NetModel[model]

```
Updating from Wolfram Research server ...
Updating from Wolfram Research server ...
Updating from Wolfram Research server ...

NetModel::rscloudc: You must connect to the Wolfram cloud to use the 
resource.
```

Comment: Does it not work if you disconnect your network?

Comment: @Szabolcs hi, see update, download something needs account login, but I've installed mathematica in linux/ubuntu/centos without FrontEnd. do you have any ideas?